# ipython notebook can't find python

Tags: macos, bash, python, ipython

I had a couple of Python 2 versions under home-brew. Since I was only using ipython notebook, I decided to uninstall all Python 2 instances, which turned out to be a bad idea because now I just get an error when trying start the P
ython server.

`-bash: /usr/local/bin/ipython: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

How do I solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reinstall Python 2.7 or use ipython3 instead of ipython. If you get a "command not found" error, run this command: `export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:$PATH` then try running ipython3 again.

Comment: Why can't it run with python3 ?

Comment: Because it is set to look for Python 2.7 as shown by bash: /usr/local/bin/ipython: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/ **python2.7** : bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: I just did a little bit of research and found [here](http://ipython.org/news.html) that iPython does not yet support Python 3.

Comment: but IPython 2.0 requires Python ≥ 2.7.2 or ≥ 3.3.0. It does not support Python 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 2.5, or 2.6. - but i have a Python 3.4.1 version installed

Comment: can i change the version ipython looks for ?

Comment: I just did some more research and found that the info I found was outdated. However, I found this from [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.1.0/interactive/reference.html): "For IPython on Python 3, use ipython3 in place of ipython."

Comment: I am still not sure how to solve this

Comment: Instead of running the server with the command ipython, use the command ipython3.

Comment: i tried but i get -bash: ipython3: command not found

Comment: Run this command: `export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:$PATH` then try running ipython3 again.

Comment: nope.. i did not work

Comment: Run `sudo find / -iname *ipython3*` and tell me the output.